# What makes "arrays" different from "object" in Javascript? [Specific reason]

Tags: javascript

As we know that the `typeof` operator in Javascript returns "object" for arrays. So, the question is why? **Is there any specific reason for that?**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var obj = { a: 1,  b: 2 };

console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);

console.log(typeof arr);
console.log(typeof obj);

console.log((typeof arr) == (typeof obj))
```

Comment: I already knew that this question is duplicate but I or we need a summary of those answers which @T.J Crowder had explained brilliantly in the below answer.  I hope that his answer would help in one or another way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: Because arrays **are** objects. They're objects with

- A specific prototype (`Array.prototype`, although in ES2015+ you can have array subclasses that have a custom prototype between the array and `Array.prototype`)
- A specialist dedicated literal syntax (`[...]`; only for `Array`, not for subclasses)
- Special treatment of a class of property names (called [*array indexes*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#integer-index): string property keys written in standard numeric form that, when converted to numbers, are in the range 0 <= x < 2³²-1)
- A special `length` property

But they're objects, and they can have non-array-index properties just like other objects. Here's an example:

```js
const a = [];
a.example = "this is a non-array-index property";
console.log(a.example); // "this is a non-array-index property"
console.log(a.length);  // 0 (the above isn't an array element, so it doesn't count)
```

Could `typeof` have been defined to return `"array"` rather than `object`? Sure. Functions are objects with the feature that are callable, and `typeof` returns `"function"` for them, so there's an argument for it. But it wasn't, and it can't be changed now.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I was expecting an answer like this. I already knew that it was a duplicate question. But I or maybe we want a good summary for that duplicate question which you had explained very well.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the `typeof` operator in Javascript returns "object" for arrays? Is
> there any specific reason for that?

Yes, because, in simple terms, you may regard this array:

```
['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
```

as being very close to a shorthand for this object:

```
{0: 'alpha', 1: 'beta', 2: 'gamma', 3: 'delta', length: 4}
```

In javascript, arrays and objects have their own distinct methods, properties, loops etc... but an `array` really *is* a type of `object`.